# Parallel running of several jobs in a python script

Tags: python, parallel-processing, bioinformatics

I am not a programmer and hence simple answers will be appreciated. I am a MD and am involved in a bioinformatics project.

Let's say I have a Python script, `abc.py` and I have a text file, `commandline.txt` with 113 command lines, 1 in each line, for this script to be run in parallel. I want each of these jobs to be run in its own directory called scatter.001, scatter.002, ... , scatter.113, (just a unique number for each), to be created in the directory where I am executing the script from.

I am running, Windows 7 with Python 2.7.

What is the command line for doing this? (python xyz\abc.py .......     )

PS:

```
-p 100 -m 10000000 -e 10 -k I:\Exome\Invex\analyses\PatientSet.load_maf.pkl ,UBE2Q1,RNF17,RNF10,REM1,PMM2,ZNF709,ZNF708,ZNF879,DISC1,RPL37,ZNF700,ZNF707,CAMK4,ZC3H10,ZC3H13,RNF115,ZC3H14,SPN,HMGCLL1,CEACAM5,GRIN1,DHX8,NUP98,XPC,SP4,SP5,CAMKV,SPPL3,RAB40C,RAB40A,COL7A1,GTSE1,OVCH1,FAM183B,KIAA0831,SPPL2B,ITGA8,ITGA9,MYO3B,ATP2A2,ITGA1,ITGA2,ITGA3,ITGA5,RIT1,ITGA7,TRHR,LOC100132288,DENND4A,DENND4B,TAP2,GAP43,PAMR1,HRH2,HRH3,HRH1,FBXL18,FAM169B,GHDC,SDK1,SDK2,THSD4,THSD1,ZFP161,CHST8,COL4A5,COL4A4,COL4A3,COL4A2,COL4A1,CHST1,CHST5,CHST4,ITGAX I:\Exome\Invex\analyses\First7.final_analysis_set.maf I:\Exome\Invex\temp\unzipped_power_files First7 I:\Exome\Invex\analyses\First7.individual_set.txt I:\Exome\Invex\hg19.fasta I:\Exome\Invex\hg19_encoded_by_trinucleotide.fasta I:\Exome\Invex\TCGA.hg19.June2011.gaf I:\Exome\Invex\hg19 I:\Exome\Invex\pph2_whpss_reduced I:\Exome\Invex\cosmic_num_times_each_chr_pos_mutated.tab
```

That is an example of one line in commandline.txt. I have 113 such lines, in the file..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go this way, you're getting into windows shell programming, which nobody does. (I mean somebody does it, but they're an extremely small group.)

It would be simplest if you wrote a second python script that loops through the arguments that you want to pass to the second script, and calls a functoin with those arguments.

```
from subprocess import Popen
from os import mkdir

argfile = open('commandline.txt')
for number, line in enumerate(argfile):    
    newpath = 'scatter.%03i' % number 
    mkdir(newpath)
    cmd = '../abc.py ' + line.strip()
    print 'Running %r in %r' % (cmd, newpath)
    Popen(cmd, shell=True, cwd=newpath)
```

This creates a directory, and runs your command as a separate process in that directory. Since it doesn't wait for the subprocess to finish before starting another, this gives the paralellism you want.

---

The in-series version just [waits](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#subprocess.Popen.wait) before it starts another subprocess.
Add one line at the end of the loop:

```
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, cwd=newpath)
    p.wait()
```

Comment: Thank you.

http://www.broadinstitute.org/software/invex/?q=running_invex

I am trying to run this program. They say explicitly that the processes must be run in parallel..

Comment: @Shyam_LA: there's a password. Put it on gist, if you can.

Comment: And the script "InVEX.py" we are discussing could take days for execution; not less than a second, as you have guessed..

Comment: @Shyam_LA: thanks for the update. I'll post the simplest possible parallel code i can write.

Comment: Tried your script too (hope springs eternal).. There is an error in line 7; "NameError: name 'os' is not defined".

Comment: @Shyam_LA: fixed, but i seriously doubt the results are different than Luke's.

Comment: I resolved the long and int problems, but turns out my 12G is not enough memory to run all those jobs at once. I contacted the developers and they told me running in series is okay. They recommend parallel just to save time (when you have a computing farm that can multitask like crazy). Can you please write me a neat little "series" script, for the same question?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the one I had before. The "edited" link above shows you the history. Can you run two at once? More? I'm also curious as to what your problem was.

Comment: Thank you so much! This new script works perfect. Just need one more line.. Lets say there is a file qwerty.mrshl that is generated with each job in the working directory and has to be deleted before the next job can be run successfully (essentially each job generates that file, but there is no automatic over-write; the new job just terminates with an error). Can you add a line to automatically delete this file from the working directory as soon as a job is finished?

Comment: I don't think I can run more than one (though theoretically I can with the given memory), because of this file that is generated with each job, unless I have a computing farm with an ideal directory structure. As to what the problem was, its quite complex, but suffice it to say Python and all the dependencies had to be 64 bit and I had to build one C module manually, for which had to install MS SDK v7.0 SP1 for the 64 bit C++ compiler. Had to take help from the developers (they weren't familiar with windows though) and do a lot of googling, to set everything up perfectly..

Comment: @Shyam_LA: the function you want is `os.remove`. Just call it after the process has ended (after the `wait()`). See: http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.remove Feel free to email me if you need anything else.

Comment: The code needed a bit of tweaking. Had to "import" "remove" too from "os". I think I am getting a hang of writing code now, thanks to you!  :)  . Job 2 started automatically after job 1..
Thanks for all your help and patience.. Have to give the code a few days to run now!

Comment: A side note to @Shyam_LA: if you want to limit the number of processes running at the same time, you may want to encapsulate the lines related to subprocess spawning and waiting into a function and use `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Answer (score 4):

This python script should do it in parallel:

```
import os, subprocess
n = 0
for cmd in open('commandline.txt'):
    newpath = 'scatter.%03d' % n 
    os.mkdir(newpath)
    subprocess.Popen("..\\abc.py " + cmd, shell=True, cwd=newpath)
    n += 1
```

Note that this assumes abc.py and commandline.txt are in the same directory. 
If this was not the case, you would have to update the string to something like "C:\\path\\to\\abc.py"

Comment: Thank you. My understanding is I copy these lines into a new file. Save it with a .py extension and then execute it through the command prompt. 
But, how do I make this script invoke the original "abc.py"? It seems to carry no reference to the original script in its lines.. Kindly clarify.

Comment: I see -- commandline.txt contains the _arguments_ to be passed to the script, not the full command. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you. That did create 114 (starting with 000) directories with the said names. But abc.py really didn't continue.. It froze with "Overflow error: Cannot fit 'long' into an index size integer" Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Most likely an error in abc.py.. you might need to find a programmer. Or better yet, learn some python :)

Comment: Well, it can't be an error in the script. The script is part of this package: http://www.broadinstitute.org/software/invex/ .. Its been tried and tested.. Maybe my 12G of RAM on a desktop pc isn't enough..

Comment: Did all 114 processes end with the same error? It's possible the arguments are somehow being supplied incorrectly. You could try invoking the commands manually to see if you get the same error.

Comment: The error message basically means that a number got too big. The terms 'int' and 'long' are different kinds of numbers. The technical documentation might be too dense, but can be found at http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Comment: @Shyam_LA: This is basically the same thing I'd write. The "long vs int" error didn't come from (standard) python, as the python integer types don't care about the differences between long and int. It certainly has something to do with your `abc.py`. I find it doubtful that the developers ran this on Windows. You may want to install ubuntu. I'm actually quite surprised that you got all those dependencies working in windows.

Comment: @Luke: Tried manually too; same error.. Thats a wonderful package there. I had executed half the steps already.. Too bad have to give up now, thanks to long and int..

Comment: @bukzor: Cython, SciPy, NumPy, and PyFasta packages are available as windows executables. Didn't have any problems with the first few steps in the process.. As to Ubuntu, I installed a Ubuntu 12.04 VM in VirtualBox and installed all the dependencies by "sudo apt-get", but I believe Cython is not working (I maybe be wrong), for whatever reason and hence can't use that either..

Answer (score 4):

GNU Parallel is made for exactly this kind of tasks. So if you had been running on GNU/Linux you would simply have done:

```
cat commandline.txt | parallel bash -c "mkdir scatter.{#}; cd scatter.{#}; python ../abc.py {}"
```

Since you are running on Microsoft Windows 7 you need a few more steps before you can run the above.

First install CygWin http://cygwin.com/setup.exe This will give you a basic UNIX-like environment.

Then start CygWin and install GNU Parallel under CygWin:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
```

CygWin prefers paths like /I/Exome/Invex/...; so finally you need to change the \ into /, and i: into /i in commandline.txt before giving it to parallel.

```
perl -pe 's{(.):}{/$1}g;s{\\}{/}g;' commandline.txt | parallel bash -c "mkdir scatter.{#}; cd scatter.{#}; python ../abc.py {}"
```

And then you are done.

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Comment: Is there are reason why `bash -c` is being included?

Comment: It is needed because the lines from commandline.txt contains multiple arguments. GNU Parallel will treat every line as a single argument and thus quote spaces. In this case we want the spaces to separate arguments. Therefore we need bash -c to unquote the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your script in order to make use of the multiprocessing module of Python.

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

It offers e.g. a Pool class for implementing the typical worker pattern where the data is 
being processed in parallel by 1..N workers.

"Not a programmer" is pointless here - instead of tinkering think about a better implementation by re-using existing Python modules. Writing and tinkering with something written on top is usually not much helpful.

Comment: Rewriting code is always an option, tinkering is never an option